# Sharepoint 2013 - Generate URL to take you to specific VIEW

Tags: workflow, infopath, list-view, list-form

I have a sharepoint list for which (using infopath) I have developed two form "views", one for standard user access, and one that has more fields/info, for one of the workflow process role admins.

For certain automated workflow emails, I would like to have a link that takes them directly to the list item "in the selected form view" (either general user, or the admin form).

How might I construct such a URL for insertion into emails, depending upon recipients role in the workflow?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure my comment showed up that well, above.  Here is the construction to build the URL to go to a specific (infopath generated) form, and open the form, with the specific list line item:

https://my.sharepoint.com/teams/mysite/mysubsite/Lists/mylist%20name/EditForm.aspx?DefaultView=Contract_Finalization&ID=34

Of course, I have to insert the ID.  Contract_Finalization is the name of my form

Answer (score 0):

Infopath supports query strings where the form is hosted on a page via an infopath web part. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form/) blog post for details, but the summary is that you'll have the infopath web part connected to a query string filter web part. You'll then need a rule to go to the appropriate screen based on the incoming value.

Comment: Hm....I had seen that blog post already.  Not sure it is exactly what I want to do.  basically, from a sharepoint workflow, I am sending a notification to a particular person, and in the notification, I want to have a link to the specific item (ID) and form that I want them to use.  The list has two forms, one for general submission, and one for an "admin" form.  I am sending a notification to an Admin, and thus, I want to have the link in the email point to a specific item in the SP list, and open it in the Admin form (vs the default user edit form).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Right. You can easily link to a specific item via the id. You can't link to a specific form. You can, however, pass data to the form, as noted in the blog post, and then use that data to determine which form to switch to.

Comment: I actually did figure it out, and you can do it.  Here is the construct, should anyone follow in my footsteps:

>https://my.sharepoint.com/teams/mysite/mysubsite/Lists/mylist%20name/EditForm.aspx?DefaultView=Contract_Finalization&ID=34   (of course, I have to insert the ID)